# Key combination in IDE that makes the opened file read-only?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2

I occasionally (approx. every 2 weeks) have an issue where copy/paste fails in my Delphi XE2 IDE - the clipboard contents 'refuse' to paste back into the currently open file.
After that I can then also no longer type.

It is as if that file has become read-only.

Is there perhaps a key combination that I accidentally pressed that made the open file read-only? In that case, I can press it again to revert the situation.
It would have to be something with <kbd>Shift</kbd> and/or <kbd>Ins</kbd> (I still paste the old fashioned way, not with <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>).

Searching through Cary Jensen's [Delphi's Editor Key and Key Combinations](http://www.jensendatasystems.com/DelphiEditorKeyTable.pdf) I could not find one.

Setup:

- Delphi XE2 on Win7/64 in VMWare Workstation
- GExperts plugin installed. IIRC the issue goes back before that, but I will now uninstall it just in case.
- The VM is still responsive when this happens (I did not check CPU usage).

Comment: Check the debugger settings - it has a tick to make "buffers read-only", sometimes it seems it fail to undo it when execution of program stops

Comment: "After that I can then also no longer type." - right-click into editor and in the context menu remove "read only" tick

Comment: I've never had XE2 do this, but D2010 used to do it to me all the time.  Best guess was that it was just an IDE bug...  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2774323/327083

Comment: Thanks J. I have just voted my own question to close as a duplicate ;-)